# Angular library using Tailwind

Tags: angular, tailwind-3

I'm currently working on an angular14 project where we would like to create a library published into our private repo in order to share look 'n feel across other (angular) applications.

I've currently setup a very basis application "sample-tailwind-app" where I use a "sample-library-lib" project containing a very simple "SampleButtonComponent" with the following html:

```
<p class="custom">This is a sample button</p>
```

The sample-button-component.scss linked with the component contains the following:

```
.custom {
  @apply font-bold underline;
}
```

From my main (sample-tailwind-app), I can see the "This is a sample button" text in the browser, however the "font-bold" and "underline" styling is not applied.

Tailwind is working for the components inside the main project, but is not for the components from the library.

App.component.html contains:

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
  Hello world!
</h1>

<p class="sample">This is a test</p>

<lib-sample-button></lib-sample-button>
```

the sample css class, font-bold and underline are working as expected.

app.component.scss:

```
.sample {
  @apply font-bold underline;
}
```

My tailwind.config.ts:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{html,ts,scss}",
    **"./node_modules/sample-library-lib/**/*.{html,ts,scss}",**
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

Is there any way to get this working with libraries?

Kind regards,

Koen

Answer (score 2):

You can add './node_modules/sample-library-lib/esm2020/**/*.mjs' this line to content array. It should fix the problem.

Comment: It was what I needed, but I changed esm2020 to esm2022.